# Copying Youtube link to my app creates NPE inside onActivityResult()

Tags: android, youtube, bundle

First of all I looked every similar questions in SO. My issue is I'm sending intent to youtube and (by making changes in manifest file) I'm able to put my app in the "share" option of youtube app. The issue is when I try to get back the extras from onActivityResult() I get NPE.

This is the code I'm sending to open the Youtube app.

```
    Intent intent2 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent2.setData(Uri.parse("https://www.youtube.com/"));
    intent2.setPackage("com.google.android.youtube");
    startActivityForResult(intent2, YOUTUBE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

When the Youtube app opens I choose "share" and pick my own app from the choices. Then in my app I use

```
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  ....
  Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
  if (extras != null){
  youtubelink = extras.getString(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);}}
```

and get a nice NPE.

The issue is as I said I need to use this bundle not in the onCreate() method but in onActivityResult(). What is your opinion , thank you.

Comment: Are you checking to make sure the result is using the same request code? From what you posted, it doesn't look like you're doing that.

Comment: Yes sir, I just put dots above but no problem with the RequestCode.. Actually when I try this bundle in Oncreate() method it's working fine but the problem is when I try to use in onActivityResult() as mentioned.

Comment: Have you checked what's in the resulting Intent, `data`?

Comment: I dont know how to check it , what should I look for?

Comment: well it's also an Intent, so use it instead of getIntent().

Comment: again NPE unfortunately

Comment: Where do you actually get the exception?

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Bundle android.content.Intent.getExtras()' on a null object reference xxxx.NewEntry.onActivityResult(NewEntry.java:772)                    
when I use    Bundle extras = data.getExtras()   in onActivityResult()